# UIView with custom init not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view, that I use as header in tableView. View is very simple, it has only label inside. The problem that if I define a custom init with string assignment inside it doesn't work.

The code is following

```
class ProducutDetailsTableViewHeader: UIView {

var sectionTitle: UILabel = {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 13)
    label.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 107/255, green: 107/255, blue: 118/255, alpha: 1.0)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(sectionTitle)

    sectionTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
    sectionTitle.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 242/255, green: 242/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

init(text: String) {
    sectionTitle.text = text
    super.init(frame: .zero)
}
}
```

If I use the following code, I don't get my header visible

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        return ProducutDetailsTableViewHeader(text: "PREVED") 
    }
    return nil
}
```

But with this code everything is okay

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        let view = ProducutDetailsTableViewHeader()
        view.sectionTitle.text = "Preved"
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Looks like I do something wrong with inits. What exactly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your `init(text: String)` method, see if this works:

```
convenience init(text: String) {
    self.init(frame: .zero)
    sectionTitle.text = text
}
```

When you call super.init you are calling the default init method of UIViewController, not **your** init method. By calling self.init you ensure that you are calling the correct method.

Comment: so the `self.init` calls this line `override init(frame: CGRect)`... which eventually calls `super.init` right?

Comment: yeah thats right, super.init calls the parent class, self calls the one you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom view with nib, then there is no need to give 'init' method separately.

In this case you need to load view from bundle using following,

*let subViewArray = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NibName", owner: self, options: nil)
let subview = subViewArray[0]*

If you will use init method your contents of your view will be nil. 
Let me know if you have nay more queries.